# How do I modify values in a HashMap in Rust?

Tags: rust, hashmap

If I had a Hashmap in Rust and I wanted to get a value and modify it, for example, lets say the value is a type u32 and I want to increment it, what is the best way to do that? I found an example that works but I am wondering of there a "Best Practices" way to do it. The example I found that does the job is:

```
`use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("Key".to_owned(), RefCell::new(0));
    let value = map.get("Key").unwrap();
    *value.borrow_mut() += 1;
    println!("{:?}", value.borrow());
}`
```

Which worked for me, but I was suspicious of using RefCell for this. Is there a better way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: [`HashMap::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut) returns a mutable reference which can be used to mutate the underlying value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I'm suspicious of that `RefCell` too. You'd use that if you had a *very specific* requirement, such as the interior mutability capabilities of `RecCell`.

I don't see why you can't just use the example code and ditch the `RefCell`.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("Key".to_owned(), 0);
    
    let value = map.get_mut("Key").unwrap();
    *value += 1;
    println!("{:?}", value);
    
    let read_value = map.get("Key").unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", read_value);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a23a90c4df7eb010945980b9b95eb031

Comment: Note, the extra `{` block is just because I wanted `value` to go out of scope so that I can borrow from the HashMap _again_. If I don't have it, the compiler complains that I've borrowed mutably (via `get_mut`) and now want to borrow immutably.

Comment: FWIW, non-lexical lifetimes [were stabilized in Rust 1.63](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/08/05/nll-by-default.html), so from then on you do not need the extra block to explicitly make `value` go out of scope.

Comment: That's what I thought; but on the rust playground it complained. Or maybe I had a typo.

Comment: To share a playground example, you have to click on the "Share" and then send the permanent link.

Comment: Just noticed that too. Fixed it!

Comment: This is great! I don't know how but I was completely unaware of .get_mut(...). Thank you very much!!

Comment: Very welcome. And for more sophisticated use cases, also take a look at the `entry` method. Something like

`map.entry("Key".to_string()).or_insert(0).and_modify(|value| *value += 1);`

Comment: PS: If you're happy with the answer, you can _accept_ it :)

Comment: Ah thank you. I have been a long term lurker on here, just getting the hang of asking questions now. thanks again!

Comment: I'm suspicious of this `RefCell` because it wraps an integer - it should have been `Cell` :)

Answer (score 1):

[`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) provides **run time** borrow checking, as opposed to **compile time** borrow checking which you would otherwise get.

In many cases you do not need that - you can just use [get_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut) as suggested in the comments and by @cadolphs.

However if you need to get mutable access to individual elements within the map at the same time, you might use `RefCell`. For example, consider this code:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("Key".to_owned(), 0);
    map.insert("Key2".to_owned(), 1);
    let value = map.get_mut("Key").unwrap();
    let value2 = map.get("Key2").unwrap();
    *value += *value2;
    println!("{:?}", *value);
}
```

This will fail to compile because I am trying to get a second value from the hashmap while I am still holding a mutable reference to the first:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `map` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:8:18
  |
7 |     let value = map.get_mut("Key").unwrap();
  |                 ------------------ mutable borrow occurs here
8 |     let value2 = map.get("Key2").unwrap();
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
9 |     *value += *value2;
  |     ----------------- mutable borrow later used here
```

You could solve that using RefCell like this:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("Key".to_owned(), RefCell::new(0));
    map.insert("Key2".to_owned(), RefCell::new(1));
    let value = map.get("Key").unwrap();
    let value2 = map.get("Key2").unwrap();
    *value.borrow_mut() += *value2.borrow();
    println!("{:?}", *value);
}
```

Here we can get the value we intend to modify out of the hash using `get` rather than `get_mut`, so we are not borrowing the hash mutably. The hash itself is not being modified, just the values inside it - this is the pattern referred to in the Rust community as [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html).

This pattern should be used very sparingly though, only when really needed.

For one thing, you are trading a compile time check for a run time check. If you have made a mistake in your logic, you won't find out at compile time, you will find out when the code panics at runtime! You can work around that by using the `try_borrow*` versions of these methods (eg. [`try_borrow_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.try_borrow_mut)), which return a `Result` instead of panicing, but then you need to add error handling to deal with it.

Another reason is that a run time borrow check may harm the performance of your code.

My example above is a case where you can easily avoid the whole thing, because the values in the hashmap are just integers which are `Copy`, so we can just do this instead:

```
    let value2 = *map.get("Key2").unwrap();
    let value = map.get_mut("Key").unwrap();
    *value += value2;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful. When I posted the original question, I was unaware of get_mut(), which solved my issue. But I was also completely unaware of interior mutability and I am realizing there are entire section of the book I missed. Thank you again!